# Почему элемент в RecyclerView не отображается?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Добавление элемента происходит по следующей схеме: `Activity` в котором находится `Adapter` -> `Activity2`, в котором создается объект `Adapter'a` и добавляется элемент, при этом предыдущее `Activity` на паузе. При таких манипуляциях элемент и вправду попадает в список `items` в `Adapter'е`, но отображения не имеет. После пересоздания `Activity` так же нет отображения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код `Adapter'a`:

```
class TimerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var items: ArrayList<Timer> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return TimerViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_timer, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is TimerViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(items[position])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class TimerViewHolder
    constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val timerType: TextView = itemView.timer_type
        private val day: TextView = itemView.day
        private val time: TextView = itemView.time
        private val cardView: CardView = itemView.card_view
        private val colors: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(
            R.color.timer_blue,
            R.color.timer_green,
            R.color.timer_orange,
            R.color.timer_purple,
            R.color.timer_red
        )

        fun bind(timer: Timer) {
            timerType.text = timer.quoteType
            day.text = timer.day
            time.text = timer.time
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(colors[(0..colors.size).random()])
        }
    }

    fun submitTimerInfo(quoteType: String, day: String, time: String) {
        val element = Timer(quoteType, day, time)
        if (!items.contains(element)) {
            items.add(element)
            notifyItemInserted(items.indexOf(element))
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов метода из условного `Activity2`:

```
private var timerAdapter = TimerAdapter()
timerAdapter.submitTimerInfo(timerType(), day, timePicker())
```

Comment: Ничего почти не понятно и очень мало кода) Возможно, вы где-то забыли уведомить адаптер об изменениях? Не вызвали `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я нарисовал Вам схему в пейнте :) Надеюсь так более понятно. Вызов `notifyItemInserted` происходит в методе `Adapter'a` `submitTimerInfo`

Comment: Т.е. вы адаптер одной активити меняете из другой?.. Это очень неправильно. Вам надо, хотя бы, данные в списке менять, а не адаптер трогать. В общем - вам бы полностью подход к решению задачи поменять. Возможно, вам тут больше подойдёт что-то типа `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: Нет, адаптер я не меняю, лишь добавляю элемент в него из другого `Activity`, которое вызывается из `Activity`, в котором лежит `adapter`. Извините, наверное я неправильно сформулировал задачу, в следствии чего Вы неправильно меня поняли.

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы создаёте новый экземпляр адаптера во второй активити, вы явно не меняете ничего в активити первой. Это два разных экземпляра одного класса, никак меж собой не связанных. Вам надо таки startActivityForResult использовать для запуска второй активити, в ней создавать данные, устанавливать их в качестве рещультата (setResult()), закрывать активити 2 и в активити 1 ловить данные в onActivityResult. В onActivityResult вам и надо будет вызвать метод адаптера submitTimerInfo

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, спасибо. Через `Result` все успешно работает. Не подскажете, можно ли так же вызывать `Result` из адаптера? Если `Activity` запускается по клику элемента там.

Comment: startActivityForResult это, вроде, метод контекста. Соответственно, почти всегда должно сработать. В адаптере, если имеется в виду что-то типа `itemView.context.startActivityForResult()` - работать точно будет. Однако, это некрасиво с точки зрения разделения ответственности и всё такое. Лучше прокидывать интерфейс в адаптер (реализовать его в активити/фрагменте, в реализации уже навигацию делать)

Comment: Нет, у `itemView.context` нет такого метода. Есть лишь обычный `startActivity()`. Вообще я реализовал это через ResultContract, вот https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result, но это было `Activity`. В адаптере такой ход не прокатывает.

Comment: ResultContract - да, более правильный способ) Работать должно, если вы контекст к Activity скастуете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно порекомендовал [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) в комментариях, ответ был найден в получении результата из `Activity` с помощью `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()`.

```
private val resultContract =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                // действие
            }
        }
```

Подробнее про `ResultContract` в [этой документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) от Google.